# What does negative length vectors in a wireframe plot (lattice package) means?

Tags: r, lattice

I want to plot a wireframe in R using the lattice package. However, I get the following error message "error using packet 1 negative length vectors are not allowed". The data looks like the following:

```
> result_mean
  experiment alpha beta   packet
1          0   1.0    1 3.000000
2          0   1.1    1 2.571429
```

The command to create the data is the following

```
  png(file=paste("foobar.png"),width=1280, height=1280);
    plot <- wireframe(result_mean$packet ~ result_mean$alpha * result_mean$beta,       
      data=result_mean, scales = list(arrows=FALSE, cex= .45, col = "black", font = 3),
      drape = TRUE, colorkey = TRUE, main = "Foo",
      col.regions = terrain.colors(100),
      screen = list(z = -60, x = -60),
      xlab="alpha", ylab="beta", zlab="mean \npackets");
  print(plot);
  dev.off();
```

I'm wondering what this error message means and if there is a good way to debug this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) `traceback()` can help pinpoint exactly where things go wrong, (2) Try to pare down your code to the simplest possible data set and plot that generates this error, and then share the data with us using `dput`.

Comment: The problem is that, the error is printed in the figure and not in the R session (where I execute the script by using the source command), so traceback() gives no information at all.

Comment: a minor point is that if you specify `data=result_mean` (as you have), then you can just express the formula as `packet~alpha*beta`, which is more readable and turns out to be slightly more robust in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging lattice graphics is a bit difficult because (a) the code is complex and multi-layered and (b) the errors get trapped in a way that makes them hard to intercept.  However, you can at least get some way in *diagnosing* the problem.

First create a minimal example.  I suspected that your problem was that your data fall on a single line, so I created data that looked like that:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1.1),
                y=c(1,1),
                z=c(2,3))

library(lattice)
wireframe(z~y*x,data=d)
```

Now confirm that fully three-dimensional data (data that define a plane) work just fine:

```
d2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=c(1,1.1),
                             y=c(1,1.1)),
                 z=1:4)
wireframe(z~y*x,data=d2)
```

So the question is really -- did you intend to draw a wireframe of two points lying on a line?  If so, what did you want to have appear in the plot?  You could hack things a little bit to set the `y` values to differ by a tiny bit -- I tried it, though, and got no wireframe appearing (but no error either).

**edit**: I did a bit more tracing, with various `debug()` incantations (and searching the source code of the `lattice` package and `R` itself for "negative length") to deduce the following: within a function called `lattice:::panel.3dwire`, there is a call to a C function `wireframePanelCalculations`, which you can see at https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/threeDplot.c?view=markup&root=lattice

Within this function:

```
nh = (nx-1) * (ny-1) * ng; /* number of quadrilaterals */
sHeights = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, nh));
```

In this case `nx` is zero, so this code is asking R to allocate a negative-length vector, which is where the error comes from.

In this case, though, I think the diagnosis is more useful than the explicit debugging.

Comment: +1 Very nice, and great point about the difficulties introduced by **lattice**' error-catching. I had never put my finger on that, but you're completely right. Something to keep in mind in writing my own code.

Comment: Well, the data I want to plot is a bit different. I'm running a series of experiments with replications. Each replication has a result and I want to compute the mean value of a result and compare it to the other (mean) values of other experiments. The alpha, beta values represent parameter settings which change from experiment to experiment and the packet value is the mean value I'm interested in. The idea was to analyze how this value evolves over different parameter settings. However, the log file (containing) the results is quite huge and I want to test it beforehand.

Comment: Well, the real question is whether data like your two-dimensional example above are going to happen in your real application, or whether in reducing the data to only two points you reduced it something slightly weird that `wireframe` can't handle ...